# App Crashes when I Switch Tab (Fragment) with countdowntimer

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, countdowntimer

Im new to android developing, I making a app that has a countdown timer on it.
The countdown timer works fine, but when I switch tabs, it crashes the moment I switch.

Here is my code on the tab 1:

```
public class FragmentTab1 extends Fragment {


Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
int year = calendar.getTime().getYear();
String year1 = String.valueOf(year);

Date date = new Date(year + 1,0,1,0,0);
long dtMili = System.currentTimeMillis();
Date dateNow = new Date(dtMili);
long remain = date.getTime() - dateNow.getTime();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstance){
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container,false);
    Log.d("Current Year",year1);
    return rootView;
}


CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(remain, 1000){

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //action for every tick of the countdown.
        TextView tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtTimer);
        tv.setText(timeCalculate(millisUntilFinished/1000) + " Countdown");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //action for when the timer has finished
        TextView tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtTimer);
        tv.setText("Happy New Year");
    }

}.start();
```

I don't have any added code on the tabListener.
When I comment out the Countdowntimer. It works fine, So I came up that the countdowntimer must have been causing the crash.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: paste your logcat what error its showing after crashing your application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Fragment's view gets destroyed when you navigate away from it.  Your timer, however, continues to run.

This means You'll get a NullPointerException on the next timer tick after you navigate to a different tab.

To prevent this, cancel your timer in onDestroyView()

Also, it'd be safer to start your timer in onActivityCreated(Bundle) since you'll be guaranteed to have created your fragment View by then.

See this on Fragment lifecycle for more info:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle

Comment: thanks! sometimes I find it hard to navigate on androids documents page. They always feed you up with lots of information. and less samples IMO of course. thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help!  That's why stack overflow is so useful, eh?  We've all got real world problems someone else has already run into.